# Why is onUpdate() called for my widgets even though I have a configuration activity?

Tags: android, configuration, android-appwidget

As far as I can tell, if I have defined a configuration activity for my widget then `onUpdate` should not be called when it is first created. It would be the configuration activity's responsibility to perform the initial configuration of the widget.

Why is it then that I still get calls to `onUpdate` in the widget provider, and after that call the configuration activity is started. If I cancel the configuration activity I get no visible widget on the home screen. If I have cancelled a widget configuration (by pressing back in the configuration activity) and reinstall the APK all the widgets, including the cancelled ones, each gets mentioned in calls to `onUpdate`.

Surely this shouldn't be so. And if it is, then how do I get rid of the widgets that was cancelled during configuration.

I'm running my code on the emulator with Android 1.6.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a bug on that:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13755#c0